# Gimp: Cut And Paste Rectangle on New Layer

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, gnu, gimp

I have an image open.  I then made a rectangle.  I then cut out the rectangle.  I then created a New Layer called loveLanguage.  I am now trying to paste the contents of the cut-rectangle it onto this New Layer I created but gimp isn't doing what I'm expecting it to do.  I am learning here.  How Do I paste the contents of the rectangle so I can save the contents of the rectangle as it's own image.

[image]

Comment: If you cut something, you can use `Edit->Paste as->New image` to create a new image that you can later save or export to a file. Try the [tutorials](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paste a selected area into a new image, use the Rectangle Select Tool (<kbd>R</kbd>), then choose `Edit -> Paste as -> New Image` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

If you just want to crop the image, use the Crop Tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) or the Rectangle Select Tool followed by `Image -> Crop to Selection`.